# How to speed up WSL2 internet download speed

Tags: networking, ubuntu, internet, hyper-v, hypervisor

I tried to use Windows Subsystem For Linux(WSL) 2 to use ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 and 11. But it has too bad internet speed in WSL2 ubuntu system. I had tried ubuntu on WSL1 as well, it also has too bad speed. It has almost 1/10 internet speed than host PC's internet speed in Task Manager / Performance.

I noticed that WSL Ethernet is working through Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter.

**Is there any way to increase internet download speed in WSL2 by adjusting Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter Band-Width Limit or doing something else?**

Comment: How exactly are you checking the speed in WSL 1/2 and how exactly are you checking it in Windows? What are the values you get? What’s your internet connection’s rated speed (it’s in the contract)?